# Runtime Annotation Processing

Tags: java, annotations

My question is as follows; please assist.

I have an annotation applicable to methods only that i want to be processed at runtime, say

```
                    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
                    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
                     public @interface MyAnno {
                          String name();}
```

And here is my processor:

```
                   public class MyAnnoProcessor(Class cls){
                        Method[] m = cls.getClass().getMethods();
                        ...// read the value passed to name and create an instance of an object depending on the value of 'name'
```

Yes. MyAnnoProcessor code is as follows:

```
              public class MyAnnoProcessor(Class cls){
                 Method[] methods = cls.getMethods();
                 for(Method m: methods){
                    MyAnno an = (MyAnno) m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
                    if(an!=null)
                       sysout(an.name());
                       ....//call another method to create a class based on the value passed to 'name'
```

Now, i have a class where i want to write many methods annotated with @MyAnno but each method passes a different value to "name". Am just unable to figure out a way to handle the annotation processing in an ideal way? How should 'MyAnnoProcessor' know what (object) needs to be returned to which method?

Say, i do this in a method A:

```
                @MyAnno(name="testA")
                public void A(){
                    MyAnnoProcessor(this); 
                ...}
```

And again i do this in method B:

```
                  @MyAnno(name="testB")
                  public void B(){
                     MyAnnoProcessor(this);
                  ...}
```

The 'MyAnnoProcessor' seems to read the value of 'name' as "testA" and not "testB" in the subsequent call to it from method B. Where am i mistaken? Please advise.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code for the `MyAnnoProcessor` class? You are getting all the methods but at some point you should distinguish between `A()` and `B()` to process the annotations correctly right?

Comment: You'll have to edit your question and paste the code. I'm seeing even less code now.

Comment: Yes, edited it in the question. Am not sure how to distinguish on whether it is A() or B() calling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find annotations for a single method, you could first get the method using reflection and the do a [`getDeclaredAnnotations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations()). Something like

`Class  clazz = ...//obtain class object
Method method =  clazz.getMethod("A", null);`

Alternatively, with your current code, you can still loop through all methods and do a matching for the method name by doing `m.getName()` inside your `for` loop to find out which method you're looking at right now.

P.S: I'm not entirely sure your code would compile (MyAnnoProcessor, i don't see any methods) and please try to follow naming conventions for methods)

Comment: Thanks. I want an annotation processor that would just return an instance of an object based on the value passed to 'name' on the annotated method. That is, @MyAnno(name="Person")public void doSthWithperson(){// and Person instance becomes available here via the annotation processor} or @MyAnno(name="Employee") public void doSthWithEmployee(){//and Employee instance is made available by the annotation processor}. Would this be possible without passing the annotated method explicitly to the annotation processor?